# React PureComponent and shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I know about PureComponent, but from the deep thought, I got confused about it.

`ShouldComponentUpdate` function is invoked when state or props are changed. So, we definitely know that something in state or props are changed if `ShouldComponentUpdate` is invoked. And those changes should be reflected in component view also. If state or props are not changed, `shouldComponentUpdate` is never called.

The `PureComponent` provides shallow comparison between old state or props and new state or props and if they are identical, it does not render. But we already know that the fact that `shouldComponentUpdate` is called means that new state or props are not same as old state or props.

Logically, I am confused about it so I got to post this question. Could you please give some advice for it?

Comment: https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81 this may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I know.. use immutable instead of mutating current object for change detection. But logically I do not understand fully.. shouldcomponentupdate invoking already implies that state or props are changed..

Comment: shouldcomponentupdate invoking in pure component or in component?

Comment: in pure component

Comment: purecomponent itself has shouldcomponentupdate function but it invokes component's one too, in the cases where you really do not want to update the component. this is why it invokes.

Comment: Thank you @Justcode, I will think about it more. To me, it is still unclear... if I have more question, will ask again.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: this is my understanding, so others please feel free to comment any issues/corrections**

You've made an incorrect assumption in your question. You think for a plain `React.Component` that if nothing has changed in state/props then `shouldComponentUpdate` is never called and it won't re-render. That's not true, for example if a plain component's parent re-renders and that parent passes props to the child, the child will re-render too. Even if those prop values that it's passing are actually the same (you can test this by putting a `console.log` in the child's `render()` function). However, even though the child will re-render, nothing will actually change (in terms of the DOM) since the props are the same. So *technically* it did an unnecessary re-render.

In a plain component, `shouldComponentUpdate` always returns true (assuming you haven't explicitly defined it). So if the props/state are the same it will always re-render, it's just that if there aren't any pertinent differences, the DOM won't change in any way. However, in a `PureComponent` it will actually do a shallow comparison of the new state/props, and only trigger a re-render if they've changed. The idea is that it implements a `shouldComponentUpdate` method for you.

For components that don't often want to change, doing this shallow comparison (which is relatively quick and cheap) is better than constantly just re-rendering regardless of any changes. To summarise, pure components prevent unnecessary re-renders by doing comparisons of state/props before re-rendering, and making sure they're actually different.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation. "That's not true, for example if a plain component's parent re-renders and that parent passes props to the child, the child will re-render too." One of that cases can be that parent's state is changed and re-render, however the props of the child are not changed, so does not need to re-render. I kind of understand it now. I think I can do more experiment with multiple children either. Thank you so much for your help!!